# How to represent local significant differences between curves

Tags: python, matlab, plot, statistics, data-visualization

I want to compare some curves to a 'normality corridor', and I would like to show in what regions (x values) the difference is significant.Take the example below, where I want to compare the dashed lines with the green band:

[image: Curve comparison]

Each curve represents the median of some values. The curves are not continuous: they only have values at integer x locations, therefore I compare them to the normality corridor at 1, 2, 3, etc.

For the "Width" group I want to show that the difference is significant between all curves and the green band between x=1 and x=3, then only two curves between 4 and 6, then only one curve between 7-8, then two curves etc etc etc...

The problem is that I have 12 groups, each with 3 curves and its own normality corridor, and each of them with 17 levels (integer values of x). That makes for a lot of p-values. Here is what I came up with for the groups in the example, with the number of asterisks representing the p-value, but I think the message can be made clearer:

[image]

TL;DR: How to represent local significant differences between curves and a normality corridor, OR how to represent lots of p-values?

Edit: Already ask this question on [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345660/how-to-represent-local-significant-differences-between-curves), but got no answers. Acknowledging this [as per netiquette](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159/7975785)

Edit 2: I will be implementing the plot in either Matlab or Python (hence the tags), but I could potentially implement a visual solution obtained in any other language.

Comment: Why exactly is this tagged with [tag:matlab] and [tag:python]? There's not one line of code in either of those languages in the question, nor are they mentioned at all...

Comment: I will be implementing the plot in either Matlab or Python, but I could potentially implement a visual solution obtained in any other language. Added an explanation to the question, although I thought it would be kinda self-explanatory...